# Table with one item on each row with a few properties in Aurelia via HTML loop

Tags: aurelia

I want to create a CSS grid with columns that have auto widths so that it fits the data in a way that makes the most sense automatically.
My problem is that I don't know have the same automatic columns widths for each column when looping through a list of items that produces a grid with 4 columns.

Temporarily, I set the first 2 columns to a set pixel amount, but I would like them to all be matching automatic widths.

HTML

```
<div repeat.for="milestone of milestoneHistory">
   <div class="grid">
      <div>${milestone.statusDescription}</div>
      <div>${milestone.quantity}</div>
      <div>${milestone.milestoneDate | dateTime}</div>
      <div>${milestone.createDate | dateTimeFromUtc}</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

SASS

```
.grid {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 100px 75px auto auto;
   //grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto; //This is how the first picture is styled
   border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;

   &.header {
      font-weight: 600;
      border-bottom: 2px solid @black;
      margin-bottom: 3px;
   }
}
```

I want it to go from this:

[image]

To something more like this this:

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason you didn't want to go for table? Did you try `table-layout: fixed` to control the width of columns? It will give you the same benefits with simple table layout like your requirement. If your plan is to use grid, maybe you can try flex box first, I think it's still simpler than grid for table layout

Comment: Good thoughts, but I think that still leaves me with the problem of each row's columns being sized individually.
I would need to iterate over all of the properties in the list of objects in order to do that. What I believe I'm limited to now is iterating over each object in the list, then picking out each of the 4 properties in that row.

Comment: with table, you don't size cell column individually, you only need to do it for the first row (normally header row), and everything else follows.